# VLC won't play DVD Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: vlc, dvd

I try to play the DVD "Toy Story" with VLC player and installed libdvdcss2, but when I attempt to play it, VLC just closes.
I already ran VLC from the console to get more output before it crashes and this is the output:

```
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.2.0
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
libdvdnav: DVD Title: TOYSTORY1
libdvdnav: DVD Serial Number: 3C2B9B99
libdvdnav: DVD Title (Alternative): TOYSTORY1
libdvdnav: Unable to find map file '/home/username/.dvdnav/TOYSTORY1.map'
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2

libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
libdvdread: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient

libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB at 0x00000268
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB at 0x00000b00
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB at 0x00000b10
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_0.VOB at 0x000011c0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_1.VOB at 0x000011d0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_0.VOB at 0x000011c0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_1.VOB at 0x000011d0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_0.VOB at 0x000011c0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_1.VOB at 0x000011d0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_0.VOB at 0x000011c0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_1.VOB at 0x000011d0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_0.VOB at 0x000011c0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_1.VOB at 0x000011d0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_07_0.VOB at 0x000011c0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_07_1.VOB at 0x000011d0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_08_0.VOB at 0x000011c0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_08_1.VOB at 0x000011d0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_09_1.VOB at 0x00001337
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_10_0.VOB at 0x00001425
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_10_1.VOB at 0x000016d8
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_11_1.VOB at 0x000024c1
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_12_0.VOB at 0x00003684
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_12_1.VOB at 0x0000a9f4
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_13_1.VOB at 0x00010451
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_14_1.VOB at 0x0004727a
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_15_0.VOB at 0x00061aa7
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_15_1.VOB at 0x000aae7c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_16_0.VOB at 0x00061aa7
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_16_1.VOB at 0x000aae7c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_17_0.VOB at 0x00061aa7
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_17_1.VOB at 0x000aae7c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_18_0.VOB at 0x00061aa7
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_18_1.VOB at 0x000aae7c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_19_0.VOB at 0x00061aa7
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_19_1.VOB at 0x000aae7c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_20_0.VOB at 0x00061aa7
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_20_1.VOB at 0x000aae7c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_21_0.VOB at 0x00061aa7
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_21_1.VOB at 0x000aae7c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_22_0.VOB at 0x00061aa7
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_22_1.VOB at 0x000aae7c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_23_0.VOB at 0x00061aa7
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_23_1.VOB at 0x000aae7c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_24_0.VOB at 0x00061aa7
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_24_1.VOB at 0x000aae7c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_25_0.VOB at 0x00061aa7
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_25_1.VOB at 0x000aae7c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_26_1.VOB at 0x002cc2a3
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_27_1.VOB at 0x002df2e3
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_28_0.VOB at 0x0033d2bb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_28_1.VOB at 0x0033d2cb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_29_0.VOB at 0x0033d2bb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_29_1.VOB at 0x0033d2cb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_30_0.VOB at 0x0033d2bb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_30_1.VOB at 0x0033d2cb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Found 30 VTS's
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0

*** libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in ifo_read.c:1264 ***
*** for vts_ptt_srpt->title[i].ptt[j].pgn != 0 ***


*** libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in ifo_read.c:1994 ***
*** for pgci_ut->nr_of_lus < 100 ***

No VTS_TMAPT available - skipping.
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

The last line says "Memory read error (Memory dump written)"

**EDIT:** When opening the DVD, VLC's memory usage goes up to 3,8GB of the 4GB avaiable to my Computer, which is probably the cause of the problem.

I hope someone of you has come across this error before and knows what to do!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is unfortunately a [known problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdvdread/+bug/377414) at the minute for several films where `libdvdread` uses excessive memory, as you note that it did in your case. The bug description at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdvdread/+bug/377414) goes as follows:

> libdvdread runs out of memory following libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in ifo_read.c:1913 on certain DVDs

The actual `ifo_read` may be different in your case, but it is the same bug, and Toy Story 1 is mentioned on the page.

This appears to happen on certain dvds and particularly some dvd9s (8gb+ DVDs).

There isn't a lot to do, apart from clicking that the bug affects you. (Toy story 1 has already been mentioned).
**However**, there is an unofficial [patch at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdvdread/+bug/377414/+attachment/3473613/+files/reference-tracking.patch) that

> adds reference counting to avoid getting stuck re-reading repeated language unit tables and pgc's.
>   The patch specifically mentions it fixes "Up" and "Dark Knight" but may well improve reading of other similar dvds.

The patch may cause regressions with other DVDs, so it is up to you if you try it, but please provide feedback at the Launchpad page if you do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Tools > Preferences > Show settings: ALL
Input codecs > Access modules > DVD with menus
Uncheck the option "Start directly in menu".
Save the preferences, close and restart VLC.
Information was obtained from [here](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=72217).

Comment: I tried this solution, but VLC still crashes, giving me the same error message as before. Although it did not solve the problem, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Work-around that worked for me with "Iron Man 3":

```
vlc dvdsimple://dvd/sr0#1:1 :disc-caching=300 :start-time=1.000
```

Just replace sr0 with your DVD and adjust eventually the start time. (found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdvdread/+bug/377414))

Alternatively, using `banshee` worked MUCH better for me!